# Summarize customer level data sql sas

Tags: sql, sas

I'm using an account level data, which has duplicate customer level data. I wish to summarise at unique customer level. A customer might have 2 or more accounts.

The structure is like this -

```
Cust Acc  
A1   A001  
A1   A002  
B1   B001  
B2   B006  
B2   B007  
B2   B008
```

I wish to get my data at unique customer level with Number of account assigned to each. Like this -

```
A1 2  
B1 1  
B2 3
```

Hope this is quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic group by;

```
select Cust, count(*) from table group by Cust
```